# Why does reversing the order of declaration in string arrays in strings.xml change things?

Tags: java, android

My arrays are declared like so in my strings.xml file:

```
<string-array name="metal_array">
    <item >Copper</item>
    <item >Aluminum</item>
</string-array>
 <string-array name="temperature_array">
    <item >60C&#x00B0;, 140F&#x00B0;</item>
    <item >75C&#x00B0;, 167F&#x00B0;</item>
    <item >90C&#x00B0;, 194F&#x00B0;</item>
</string-array>
```

and adapters added in the onCreate() method of the activity:

```
    Spinner metalSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.metal_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> metalAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.metal_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    metalAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    metalSpinner.setAdapter(metalAdapter);

    Spinner temperatureSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.temperature_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> temperatureAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.temperature_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    temperatureAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    temperatureSpinner.setAdapter(temperatureAdapter);
```

Without any changes to the activity.xml file, simply switching the order that the two arrays are declared in the strings.xml file reverses which spinner the array is placed into. This makes no sense to me, since everything is referenced by name. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays XMLs are getting compiled into class files where their names getting turned into integer based IDs. When you changed the order, they get recompiled and elements get new IDs. For you out come is, any class files using old IDs will behave in funny ways.